# Creating list columns in spfx Web Part

Tags: column, spfx, spfx-webparts, elements-xml

I am able to create a custom list in spfx webpart through elements.xml with the following xml snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
    <ListInstance   
            FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"  
            Title="TestSPFxList3"   
            Description="New SP List"  
            TemplateType="100"  
            Url="Lists/TestSPFxList3">  
    </ListInstance>  
</Elements>
```

How do I add columns to it.? Let's say column "Name" and "EmailId".

Answer (score 4):

You need to wrap it inside the `<Field>` tag as below in the element.xml file.

```
<Field ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}"
            Name="EmailId"
            DisplayName="Email Id"
            Type="Text"
            Description ="Some desc"
            Required="TRUE"
            MaxLength="50"
            Group="SPFx Columns"></Field>
```

So, your full XML would be somewhat as below:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

    <Field ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}"
            Name="EmailId"
            DisplayName="Email Id"
            Type="Text"
            Description ="Some desc."
            Required="TRUE"
            MaxLength="50"
            Group="SPFx Columns" >

    <Field ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}"
            Name="CustomChoice"
            DisplayName="Choice Field"
            Type="Choice"
            Required="FALSE"
            Group="SPFx Columns">
        <CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Blue</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Green</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Green</CHOICE>        
        </CHOICES>
    </Field>

    <ContentType ID="0x010042D0C1C200A14B6887742B6344675C8B" 
            Name="My Content Type" 
            Group="SPFx Content Types" 
            Description="Sample content types from web part solution">
        <FieldRefs>
            <FieldRef ID="{060E50AC-E9C1-4D3C-B1F9-DE0BCAC300F6}" /> 
            <FieldRef ID="{943E7530-5E2B-4C02-8259-CCD93A9ECB18}" />
        </FieldRefs>
    </ContentType> 

    <ListInstance   
            FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100"  
            Title="TestSPFxList3"   
            Description="New SP List"  
            TemplateType="100"  
            Url="Lists/TestSPFxList3">  
    </ListInstance> 
</Elements>
```

Reference- [Provision SP assets from package](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package)

Comment: Able to create ContentType but it is not creating the "EmailId" and "Name" fields.

Comment: Any errors ? You cant use `Name` as internal name, its a default field, replace it with something like `CustomName`. Also, try to create a new package and check.

Comment: Also, i think you need to attach that content type to the list, once you do that the field will be visible.

Comment: I followed this article: https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/web-parts/get-started/provision-sp-assets-from-package 

I was missing the schema.XML  file and operations performed in it. Not I am able to create the columns.

Comment: Also, I have a doubt about, how to create multiple lists?? Do I need to create individual files(Ex: element2.xml, schema2.xml ) for each list creation.? or I can create multiple lists from single elements.xml file.?

Comment: Just use a single element.xml and multiple schema.xml. So, for example, to create 2 lists, create list instances in the element.xml file and separate the schemas via schema.xml , schema2.xml like that.